# What is more efficient? Connecting to the DB or having a couple hundred rows in an array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, cloudflare

I'm trying to get the calling code and the country name of my visitors.

Previously, I had a connection to the DB to get the calling code and country name that matches the one we got from CloudFlare, using

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];
```

and

```
$country_code=$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT short_name, calling_code from country WHERE iso2 LIKE "'.$country_code.'"');
$country = $stmt->fetch();
```

However, when traffic gets heavy, having many connections to the DB can be problematic. So I defined this array:

```
$countries = array();
$countries['AF'] = array("code"=>"AF","short_name"=>"Afghanistan","calling_code"=>"93");
$countries['AL'] = array("code"=>"AL","short_name"=>"Albania","calling_code"=>"355");
$countries['DZ'] = array("code"=>"DZ","short_name"=>"Algeria","calling_code"=>"213");
$countries['AS'] = array("code"=>"AS","short_name"=>"American Samoa","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['AD'] = array("code"=>"AD","short_name"=>"Andorra","calling_code"=>"376");
$countries['AO'] = array("code"=>"AO","short_name"=>"Angola","calling_code"=>"244");
$countries['AI'] = array("code"=>"AI","short_name"=>"Anguilla","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['AG'] = array("code"=>"AG","short_name"=>"Antigua","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['AR'] = array("code"=>"AR","short_name"=>"Argentina","calling_code"=>"54");
$countries['AM'] = array("code"=>"AM","short_name"=>"Armenia","calling_code"=>"374");
$countries['AW'] = array("code"=>"AW","short_name"=>"Aruba","calling_code"=>"297");
$countries['AU'] = array("code"=>"AU","short_name"=>"Australia","calling_code"=>"61");
$countries['AT'] = array("code"=>"AT","short_name"=>"Austria","calling_code"=>"43");
$countries['AZ'] = array("code"=>"AZ","short_name"=>"Azerbaijan","calling_code"=>"994");
$countries['BH'] = array("code"=>"BH","short_name"=>"Bahrain","calling_code"=>"973");
$countries['BD'] = array("code"=>"BD","short_name"=>"Bangladesh","calling_code"=>"880");
$countries['BB'] = array("code"=>"BB","short_name"=>"Barbados","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['BY'] = array("code"=>"BY","short_name"=>"Belarus","calling_code"=>"375");
$countries['BE'] = array("code"=>"BE","short_name"=>"Belgium","calling_code"=>"32");
$countries['BZ'] = array("code"=>"BZ","short_name"=>"Belize","calling_code"=>"501");
$countries['BJ'] = array("code"=>"BJ","short_name"=>"Benin","calling_code"=>"229");
$countries['BM'] = array("code"=>"BM","short_name"=>"Bermuda","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['BT'] = array("code"=>"BT","short_name"=>"Bhutan","calling_code"=>"975");
$countries['BO'] = array("code"=>"BO","short_name"=>"Bolivia","calling_code"=>"591");
$countries['BA'] = array("code"=>"BA","short_name"=>"Bosnia and Herzegovina","calling_code"=>"387");
$countries['BW'] = array("code"=>"BW","short_name"=>"Botswana","calling_code"=>"267");
$countries['BR'] = array("code"=>"BR","short_name"=>"Brazil","calling_code"=>"55");
$countries['IO'] = array("code"=>"IO","short_name"=>"British Indian Ocean Territory","calling_code"=>"246");
$countries['VG'] = array("code"=>"VG","short_name"=>"British Virgin Islands","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['BN'] = array("code"=>"BN","short_name"=>"Brunei","calling_code"=>"673");
$countries['BG'] = array("code"=>"BG","short_name"=>"Bulgaria","calling_code"=>"359");
$countries['BF'] = array("code"=>"BF","short_name"=>"Burkina Faso","calling_code"=>"226");
$countries['MM'] = array("code"=>"MM","short_name"=>"Burma Myanmar" ,"calling_code"=>"95");
$countries['BI'] = array("code"=>"BI","short_name"=>"Burundi","calling_code"=>"257");
$countries['KH'] = array("code"=>"KH","short_name"=>"Cambodia","calling_code"=>"855");
$countries['CM'] = array("code"=>"CM","short_name"=>"Cameroon","calling_code"=>"237");
$countries['CA'] = array("code"=>"CA","short_name"=>"Canada","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['CV'] = array("code"=>"CV","short_name"=>"Cape Verde","calling_code"=>"238");
$countries['KY'] = array("code"=>"KY","short_name"=>"Cayman Islands","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['CF'] = array("code"=>"CF","short_name"=>"Central African Republic","calling_code"=>"236");
$countries['TD'] = array("code"=>"TD","short_name"=>"Chad","calling_code"=>"235");
$countries['CL'] = array("code"=>"CL","short_name"=>"Chile","calling_code"=>"56");
$countries['CN'] = array("code"=>"CN","short_name"=>"China","calling_code"=>"86");
$countries['CO'] = array("code"=>"CO","short_name"=>"Colombia","calling_code"=>"57");
$countries['KM'] = array("code"=>"KM","short_name"=>"Comoros","calling_code"=>"269");
$countries['CK'] = array("code"=>"CK","short_name"=>"Cook Islands","calling_code"=>"682");
$countries['CR'] = array("code"=>"CR","short_name"=>"Costa Rica","calling_code"=>"506");
$countries['CI'] = array("code"=>"CI","short_name"=>"Côte d'Ivoire" ,"calling_code"=>"225");
$countries['HR'] = array("code"=>"HR","short_name"=>"Croatia","calling_code"=>"385");
$countries['CU'] = array("code"=>"CU","short_name"=>"Cuba","calling_code"=>"53");
$countries['CY'] = array("code"=>"CY","short_name"=>"Cyprus","calling_code"=>"357");
$countries['CZ'] = array("code"=>"CZ","short_name"=>"Czech Republic","calling_code"=>"420");
$countries['CD'] = array("code"=>"CD","short_name"=>"Democratic Republic of Congo","calling_code"=>"243");
$countries['DK'] = array("code"=>"DK","short_name"=>"Denmark","calling_code"=>"45");
$countries['DJ'] = array("code"=>"DJ","short_name"=>"Djibouti","calling_code"=>"253");
$countries['DM'] = array("code"=>"DM","short_name"=>"Dominica","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['DO'] = array("code"=>"DO","short_name"=>"Dominican Republic","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['EC'] = array("code"=>"EC","short_name"=>"Ecuador","calling_code"=>"593");
$countries['EG'] = array("code"=>"EG","short_name"=>"Egypt","calling_code"=>"20");
$countries['SV'] = array("code"=>"SV","short_name"=>"El Salvador","calling_code"=>"503");
$countries['GQ'] = array("code"=>"GQ","short_name"=>"Equatorial Guinea","calling_code"=>"240");
$countries['ER'] = array("code"=>"ER","short_name"=>"Eritrea","calling_code"=>"291");
$countries['EE'] = array("code"=>"EE","short_name"=>"Estonia","calling_code"=>"372");
$countries['ET'] = array("code"=>"ET","short_name"=>"Ethiopia","calling_code"=>"251");
$countries['FK'] = array("code"=>"FK","short_name"=>"Falkland Islands","calling_code"=>"500");
$countries['FO'] = array("code"=>"FO","short_name"=>"Faroe Islands","calling_code"=>"298");
$countries['FM'] = array("code"=>"FM","short_name"=>"Federated States of Micronesia","calling_code"=>"691");
$countries['FJ'] = array("code"=>"FJ","short_name"=>"Fiji","calling_code"=>"679");
$countries['FI'] = array("code"=>"FI","short_name"=>"Finland","calling_code"=>"358");
$countries['FR'] = array("code"=>"FR","short_name"=>"France","calling_code"=>"33");
$countries['GF'] = array("code"=>"GF","short_name"=>"French Guiana","calling_code"=>"594");
$countries['PF'] = array("code"=>"PF","short_name"=>"French Polynesia","calling_code"=>"689");
$countries['GA'] = array("code"=>"GA","short_name"=>"Gabon","calling_code"=>"241");
$countries['GE'] = array("code"=>"GE","short_name"=>"Georgia","calling_code"=>"995");
$countries['DE'] = array("code"=>"DE","short_name"=>"Germany","calling_code"=>"49");
$countries['GH'] = array("code"=>"GH","short_name"=>"Ghana","calling_code"=>"233");
$countries['GI'] = array("code"=>"GI","short_name"=>"Gibraltar","calling_code"=>"350");
$countries['GR'] = array("code"=>"GR","short_name"=>"Greece","calling_code"=>"30");
$countries['GL'] = array("code"=>"GL","short_name"=>"Greenland","calling_code"=>"299");
$countries['GD'] = array("code"=>"GD","short_name"=>"Grenada","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['GP'] = array("code"=>"GP","short_name"=>"Guadeloupe","calling_code"=>"590");
$countries['GU'] = array("code"=>"GU","short_name"=>"Guam","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['GT'] = array("code"=>"GT","short_name"=>"Guatemala","calling_code"=>"502");
$countries['GN'] = array("code"=>"GN","short_name"=>"Guinea","calling_code"=>"224");
$countries['GW'] = array("code"=>"GW","short_name"=>"Guinea-Bissau","calling_code"=>"245");
$countries['GY'] = array("code"=>"GY","short_name"=>"Guyana","calling_code"=>"592");
$countries['HT'] = array("code"=>"HT","short_name"=>"Haiti","calling_code"=>"509");
$countries['HN'] = array("code"=>"HN","short_name"=>"Honduras","calling_code"=>"504");
$countries['HK'] = array("code"=>"HK","short_name"=>"Hong Kong","calling_code"=>"852");
$countries['HU'] = array("code"=>"HU","short_name"=>"Hungary","calling_code"=>"36");
$countries['IS'] = array("code"=>"IS","short_name"=>"Iceland","calling_code"=>"354");
$countries['IN'] = array("code"=>"IN","short_name"=>"India","calling_code"=>"91");
$countries['ID'] = array("code"=>"ID","short_name"=>"Indonesia","calling_code"=>"62");
$countries['IR'] = array("code"=>"IR","short_name"=>"Iran","calling_code"=>"98");
$countries['IQ'] = array("code"=>"IQ","short_name"=>"Iraq","calling_code"=>"964");
$countries['IE'] = array("code"=>"IE","short_name"=>"Ireland","calling_code"=>"353");
$countries['IL'] = array("code"=>"IL","short_name"=>"Israel","calling_code"=>"972");
$countries['IT'] = array("code"=>"IT","short_name"=>"Italy","calling_code"=>"39");
$countries['JM'] = array("code"=>"JM","short_name"=>"Jamaica","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['JP'] = array("code"=>"JP","short_name"=>"Japan","calling_code"=>"81");
$countries['JO'] = array("code"=>"JO","short_name"=>"Jordan","calling_code"=>"962");
$countries['KZ'] = array("code"=>"KZ","short_name"=>"Kazakhstan","calling_code"=>"7");
$countries['KE'] = array("code"=>"KE","short_name"=>"Kenya","calling_code"=>"254");
$countries['KI'] = array("code"=>"KI","short_name"=>"Kiribati","calling_code"=>"686");
$countries['XK'] = array("code"=>"XK","short_name"=>"Kosovo","calling_code"=>"381");
$countries['KW'] = array("code"=>"KW","short_name"=>"Kuwait","calling_code"=>"965");
$countries['KG'] = array("code"=>"KG","short_name"=>"Kyrgyzstan","calling_code"=>"996");
$countries['LA'] = array("code"=>"LA","short_name"=>"Laos","calling_code"=>"856");
$countries['LV'] = array("code"=>"LV","short_name"=>"Latvia","calling_code"=>"371");
$countries['LB'] = array("code"=>"LB","short_name"=>"Lebanon","calling_code"=>"961");
$countries['LS'] = array("code"=>"LS","short_name"=>"Lesotho","calling_code"=>"266");
$countries['LR'] = array("code"=>"LR","short_name"=>"Liberia","calling_code"=>"231");
$countries['LY'] = array("code"=>"LY","short_name"=>"Libya","calling_code"=>"218");
$countries['LI'] = array("code"=>"LI","short_name"=>"Liechtenstein","calling_code"=>"423");
$countries['LT'] = array("code"=>"LT","short_name"=>"Lithuania","calling_code"=>"370");
$countries['LU'] = array("code"=>"LU","short_name"=>"Luxembourg","calling_code"=>"352");
$countries['MO'] = array("code"=>"MO","short_name"=>"Macau","calling_code"=>"853");
$countries['MK'] = array("code"=>"MK","short_name"=>"Macedonia","calling_code"=>"389");
$countries['MG'] = array("code"=>"MG","short_name"=>"Madagascar","calling_code"=>"261");
$countries['MW'] = array("code"=>"MW","short_name"=>"Malawi","calling_code"=>"265");
$countries['MY'] = array("code"=>"MY","short_name"=>"Malaysia","calling_code"=>"60");
$countries['MV'] = array("code"=>"MV","short_name"=>"Maldives","calling_code"=>"960");
$countries['ML'] = array("code"=>"ML","short_name"=>"Mali","calling_code"=>"223");
$countries['MT'] = array("code"=>"MT","short_name"=>"Malta","calling_code"=>"356");
$countries['MH'] = array("code"=>"MH","short_name"=>"Marshall Islands","calling_code"=>"692");
$countries['MQ'] = array("code"=>"MQ","short_name"=>"Martinique","calling_code"=>"596");
$countries['MR'] = array("code"=>"MR","short_name"=>"Mauritania","calling_code"=>"222");
$countries['MU'] = array("code"=>"MU","short_name"=>"Mauritius","calling_code"=>"230");
$countries['YT'] = array("code"=>"YT","short_name"=>"Mayotte","calling_code"=>"262");
$countries['MX'] = array("code"=>"MX","short_name"=>"Mexico","calling_code"=>"52");
$countries['MD'] = array("code"=>"MD","short_name"=>"Moldova","calling_code"=>"373");
$countries['MC'] = array("code"=>"MC","short_name"=>"Monaco","calling_code"=>"377");
$countries['MN'] = array("code"=>"MN","short_name"=>"Mongolia","calling_code"=>"976");
$countries['ME'] = array("code"=>"ME","short_name"=>"Montenegro","calling_code"=>"382");
$countries['MS'] = array("code"=>"MS","short_name"=>"Montserrat","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['MA'] = array("code"=>"MA","short_name"=>"Morocco","calling_code"=>"212");
$countries['MZ'] = array("code"=>"MZ","short_name"=>"Mozambique","calling_code"=>"258");
$countries['NA'] = array("code"=>"NA","short_name"=>"Namibia","calling_code"=>"264");
$countries['NR'] = array("code"=>"NR","short_name"=>"Nauru","calling_code"=>"674");
$countries['NP'] = array("code"=>"NP","short_name"=>"Nepal","calling_code"=>"977");
$countries['NL'] = array("code"=>"NL","short_name"=>"Netherlands","calling_code"=>"31");
$countries['AN'] = array("code"=>"AN","short_name"=>"Netherlands Antilles","calling_code"=>"599");
$countries['NC'] = array("code"=>"NC","short_name"=>"New Caledonia","calling_code"=>"687");
$countries['NZ'] = array("code"=>"NZ","short_name"=>"New Zealand","calling_code"=>"64");
$countries['NI'] = array("code"=>"NI","short_name"=>"Nicaragua","calling_code"=>"505");
$countries['NE'] = array("code"=>"NE","short_name"=>"Niger","calling_code"=>"227");
$countries['NG'] = array("code"=>"NG","short_name"=>"Nigeria","calling_code"=>"234");
$countries['NU'] = array("code"=>"NU","short_name"=>"Niue","calling_code"=>"683");
$countries['NF'] = array("code"=>"NF","short_name"=>"Norfolk Island","calling_code"=>"672");
$countries['KP'] = array("code"=>"KP","short_name"=>"North Korea","calling_code"=>"850");
$countries['MP'] = array("code"=>"MP","short_name"=>"Northern Mariana Islands","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['NO'] = array("code"=>"NO","short_name"=>"Norway","calling_code"=>"47");
$countries['OM'] = array("code"=>"OM","short_name"=>"Oman","calling_code"=>"968");
$countries['PK'] = array("code"=>"PK","short_name"=>"Pakistan","calling_code"=>"92");
$countries['PW'] = array("code"=>"PW","short_name"=>"Palau","calling_code"=>"680");
$countries['PS'] = array("code"=>"PS","short_name"=>"Palestine","calling_code"=>"970");
$countries['PA'] = array("code"=>"PA","short_name"=>"Panama","calling_code"=>"507");
$countries['PG'] = array("code"=>"PG","short_name"=>"Papua New Guinea","calling_code"=>"675");
$countries['PY'] = array("code"=>"PY","short_name"=>"Paraguay","calling_code"=>"595");
$countries['PE'] = array("code"=>"PE","short_name"=>"Peru","calling_code"=>"51");
$countries['PH'] = array("code"=>"PH","short_name"=>"Philippines","calling_code"=>"63");
$countries['PL'] = array("code"=>"PL","short_name"=>"Poland","calling_code"=>"48");
$countries['PT'] = array("code"=>"PT","short_name"=>"Portugal","calling_code"=>"351");
$countries['PR'] = array("code"=>"PR","short_name"=>"Puerto Rico","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['QA'] = array("code"=>"QA","short_name"=>"Qatar","calling_code"=>"974");
$countries['CG'] = array("code"=>"CG","short_name"=>"Republic of the Congo","calling_code"=>"242");
$countries['RE'] = array("code"=>"RE","short_name"=>"Réunion" ,"calling_code"=>"262");
$countries['RO'] = array("code"=>"RO","short_name"=>"Romania","calling_code"=>"40");
$countries['RU'] = array("code"=>"RU","short_name"=>"Russia","calling_code"=>"7");
$countries['RW'] = array("code"=>"RW","short_name"=>"Rwanda","calling_code"=>"250");
$countries['BL'] = array("code"=>"BL","short_name"=>"Saint Barthélemy" ,"calling_code"=>"590");
$countries['SH'] = array("code"=>"SH","short_name"=>"Saint Helena","calling_code"=>"290");
$countries['KN'] = array("code"=>"KN","short_name"=>"Saint Kitts and Nevis","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['MF'] = array("code"=>"MF","short_name"=>"Saint Martin","calling_code"=>"590");
$countries['PM'] = array("code"=>"PM","short_name"=>"Saint Pierre and Miquelon","calling_code"=>"508");
$countries['VC'] = array("code"=>"VC","short_name"=>"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['WS'] = array("code"=>"WS","short_name"=>"Samoa","calling_code"=>"685");
$countries['SM'] = array("code"=>"SM","short_name"=>"San Marino","calling_code"=>"378");
$countries['ST'] = array("code"=>"ST","short_name"=>"São Tomé and Príncipe" ,"calling_code"=>"239");
$countries['SA'] = array("code"=>"SA","short_name"=>"Saudi Arabia","calling_code"=>"966");
$countries['SN'] = array("code"=>"SN","short_name"=>"Senegal","calling_code"=>"221");
$countries['RS'] = array("code"=>"RS","short_name"=>"Serbia","calling_code"=>"381");
$countries['SC'] = array("code"=>"SC","short_name"=>"Seychelles","calling_code"=>"248");
$countries['SL'] = array("code"=>"SL","short_name"=>"Sierra Leone","calling_code"=>"232");
$countries['SG'] = array("code"=>"SG","short_name"=>"Singapore","calling_code"=>"65");
$countries['SK'] = array("code"=>"SK","short_name"=>"Slovakia","calling_code"=>"421");
$countries['SI'] = array("code"=>"SI","short_name"=>"Slovenia","calling_code"=>"386");
$countries['SB'] = array("code"=>"SB","short_name"=>"Solomon Islands","calling_code"=>"677");
$countries['SO'] = array("code"=>"SO","short_name"=>"Somalia","calling_code"=>"252");
$countries['ZA'] = array("code"=>"ZA","short_name"=>"South Africa","calling_code"=>"27");
$countries['KR'] = array("code"=>"KR","short_name"=>"South Korea","calling_code"=>"82");
$countries['ES'] = array("code"=>"ES","short_name"=>"Spain","calling_code"=>"34");
$countries['LK'] = array("code"=>"LK","short_name"=>"Sri Lanka","calling_code"=>"94");
$countries['LC'] = array("code"=>"LC","short_name"=>"St. Lucia","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['SD'] = array("code"=>"SD","short_name"=>"Sudan","calling_code"=>"249");
$countries['SR'] = array("code"=>"SR","short_name"=>"Surishort_name","calling_code"=>"597");
$countries['SZ'] = array("code"=>"SZ","short_name"=>"Swaziland","calling_code"=>"268");
$countries['SE'] = array("code"=>"SE","short_name"=>"Sweden","calling_code"=>"46");
$countries['CH'] = array("code"=>"CH","short_name"=>"Switzerland","calling_code"=>"41");
$countries['SY'] = array("code"=>"SY","short_name"=>"Syria","calling_code"=>"963");
$countries['TW'] = array("code"=>"TW","short_name"=>"Taiwan","calling_code"=>"886");
$countries['TJ'] = array("code"=>"TJ","short_name"=>"Tajikistan","calling_code"=>"992");
$countries['TZ'] = array("code"=>"TZ","short_name"=>"Tanzania","calling_code"=>"255");
$countries['TH'] = array("code"=>"TH","short_name"=>"Thailand","calling_code"=>"66");
$countries['BS'] = array("code"=>"BS","short_name"=>"The Bahamas","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['GM'] = array("code"=>"GM","short_name"=>"The Gambia","calling_code"=>"220");
$countries['TL'] = array("code"=>"TL","short_name"=>"Timor-Leste","calling_code"=>"670");
$countries['TG'] = array("code"=>"TG","short_name"=>"Togo","calling_code"=>"228");
$countries['TK'] = array("code"=>"TK","short_name"=>"Tokelau","calling_code"=>"690");
$countries['TO'] = array("code"=>"TO","short_name"=>"Tonga","calling_code"=>"676");
$countries['TT'] = array("code"=>"TT","short_name"=>"Trinidad and Tobago","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['TN'] = array("code"=>"TN","short_name"=>"Tunisia","calling_code"=>"216");
$countries['TR'] = array("code"=>"TR","short_name"=>"Turkey","calling_code"=>"90");
$countries['TM'] = array("code"=>"TM","short_name"=>"Turkmenistan","calling_code"=>"993");
$countries['TC'] = array("code"=>"TC","short_name"=>"Turks and Caicos Islands","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['TV'] = array("code"=>"TV","short_name"=>"Tuvalu","calling_code"=>"688");
$countries['UG'] = array("code"=>"UG","short_name"=>"Uganda","calling_code"=>"256");
$countries['UA'] = array("code"=>"UA","short_name"=>"Ukraine","calling_code"=>"380");
$countries['AE'] = array("code"=>"AE","short_name"=>"United Arab Emirates","calling_code"=>"971");
$countries['GB'] = array("code"=>"GB","short_name"=>"United Kingdom","calling_code"=>"44");
$countries['US'] = array("code"=>"US","short_name"=>"United States","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['UY'] = array("code"=>"UY","short_name"=>"Uruguay","calling_code"=>"598");
$countries['VI'] = array("code"=>"VI","short_name"=>"US Virgin Islands","calling_code"=>"1");
$countries['UZ'] = array("code"=>"UZ","short_name"=>"Uzbekistan","calling_code"=>"998");
$countries['VU'] = array("code"=>"VU","short_name"=>"Vanuatu","calling_code"=>"678");
$countries['VA'] = array("code"=>"VA","short_name"=>"Vatican City","calling_code"=>"39");
$countries['VE'] = array("code"=>"VE","short_name"=>"Venezuela","calling_code"=>"58");
$countries['VN'] = array("code"=>"VN","short_name"=>"Vietnam","calling_code"=>"84");
$countries['WF'] = array("code"=>"WF","short_name"=>"Wallis and Futuna","calling_code"=>"681");
$countries['YE'] = array("code"=>"YE","short_name"=>"Yemen","calling_code"=>"967");
$countries['ZM'] = array("code"=>"ZM","short_name"=>"Zambia","calling_code"=>"260");
$countries['ZW'] = array("code"=>"ZW","short_name"=>"Zimbabwe","calling_code"=>"263");
```

and I simply fetch the values I want using:

```
$country_code=$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];
$country=$countries[''.$country_code.''];
```

Thus eliminating the need to connect to the DB and use MYSQL.

My question is, is it bad to have this array loaded several times a second? Will it impact performance a lot? Should I simply have a connection to the DB like I previously did?

The server has 16GB of RAM and 8 cores. We're talking about 40-50 thousand visits per day.

Thanks!

Comment: The way the arrays are , it's just mess inside the file , you should do code clean as possible to organise better your code , not for this time but for any other things coming on the way , try to use database and import these values inside database , and then fetch the information based on country code. if you will use database  , you can get all of the informations in any file and any page. else you have to copy and paste these arrays into every file.

Comment: The array resides in memory so it will be quicker... you could eke more performance out of the DB by using something like Redis (which will cache DB results in memory). Or you could create a `Country` class with a static `getCountries()` method - that way the list will only exist in memory as and when it's needed (in theory) and your country data will still exist in a single place... but we're not talking about a huge amount of data here.

Comment: I have one suggestion why you are not caching these data because country  will not daily change you need to do caching for country that will make you application very smoothly.

Comment: How is PHP served? Using `mod_php` or using `php-fpm`? It makes a huge difference, because if it's `php-fpm`, then you are not opening multiple database connections depending on number of visitors since those connections will be multiplexed by fpm child processes. This is very important and what's also important to know is that `php-fpm` is **very** efficient when it comes to connections to other systems. However, keeping all your data in an array will be definitely faster, even if you manage to avoid the overhead of connecting to db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: `$country=$countries[''.$country_code.''];` can be replaced with this `$country=$countries[$country_code];`

This array is definitly the better choice over a Database. Each connection needs some time and arrays can be accessed way faster.

If you want to know exactly how the difference is, you could use this "mini test suite" t determine the runtime difference.

```
$start1 = microtime(true);

for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++)
{
    //With database
}
$end1 = microtime(true);

unset(); // The variables which might have been set the section above

$start2 = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++)
{
    //code with array
}
$end2 = microtime(true);

echo $end1-$start1."<br />";
echo $end2-$start2."<br />";
```

I hope this helps you, if not please let me know.

Comment: Thanks. And yeah that one line of code is indeed redundant. Bad habits.

Comment: The first sentance in this answer doesnt make sense. Did you mean `$country=$countries[$country_code];`